# Memory Leak in Binary Tree Initialize Function

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, stack, binary-tree, valgrind

I am attempting to make and evaluate a binary expression tree based on a postfix user input string in C. My binary tree initialization function is causing memory leaks, however. To summarize my algorithm, the user enters a postfix string of input which is parsed through by a function and assembled into the tree. Here's my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

// Define binary expression tree data structure
typedef struct binExpTree {

  char *val;
  struct binExpTree *left;
  struct binExpTree *right;

} expTree;

// Define expression tree stack data structure
typedef struct expTreeStack {

  int height;
  int used;
  expTree **expTreeDarr;

} treeStack;

// Function prototypes
void initStack(treeStack *stack);

expTree * getTopStack(treeStack *stack);

int isEmptyStack(treeStack *stack);

void pushStack(treeStack *stack, expTree *treeNode);

expTree * popStack(treeStack *stack);

void clearStack(treeStack *stack);

expTree * initTree(char *val);

void printCommands();

expTree * parseExpression(char *expString);

void clearTree(expTree *rootNode);

void printInfix(expTree *rootNode);

void printPrefix(expTree *rootNode);

int evalExpression(expTree *rootNode);






/* File contains all functions necessary for stack operations */

// Initialize empty binary tree stack of size 4
void initStack(treeStack *stack) {

  stack->height = 4;
  stack->used   = 0;
  stack->expTreeDarr = (expTree **)malloc(sizeof(expTree *) * stack->height);

}

// Return the tree node from the stack's top
expTree * getTopStack(treeStack *stack) {

  if (stack->used > 0) {
    return stack->expTreeDarr[stack->used - 1];
  }
  else {
    return NULL;
  }

}

// Discern whether tree stack is empty
int isEmptyStack(treeStack *stack) {

  if (stack->used == 0) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }

}

// Push tree node pointer onto stack
void pushStack(treeStack *stack, expTree *treeNode) {

  if (stack->used == stack->height) {
    expTree **expTreeTmp = stack->expTreeDarr;
    stack->height += 4;
    stack->expTreeDarr = (expTree **)malloc(sizeof(expTree *) * stack->height);

    for (int i = 0; i < stack->used; i++) {
      stack->expTreeDarr[i] = expTreeTmp[i];
      //free(expTreeTmp[i]);
    }
    free(expTreeTmp);
  }

  stack->expTreeDarr[stack->used] = treeNode;
  stack->used = stack->used + 1;
}

// Pop tree node pointer from the stack
expTree * popStack(treeStack *stack) {
  
  expTree *stackTmp = getTopStack(stack);
  expTree *newNode = (expTree *)malloc(sizeof(expTree));
  *newNode = *stackTmp;
  
  stack->used -= 1;

  return newNode;
}

// Empty stack of all data (make sure this works)
void clearStack(treeStack *stack) {

  for (int i = 0; i < stack->used; i++) {
    clearTree(stack->expTreeDarr[i]);
  }

  free(stack->expTreeDarr);
  stack->used   = 0;
  stack->height = 0;

}

/* File contains all functions necessary for binary tree operations */

// Initialize binary expression tree with specified operator/operand

expTree * initTree(char *val) {

  expTree *newTree = (expTree *)malloc(sizeof(expTree));
  newTree->val = (char *)malloc(strlen(val) + 1);
  strcpy(newTree->val, val);
  newTree->left  = NULL;
  newTree->right = NULL;

  return newTree;

}


// Print commands available to the user
void printCommands() {
 
  printf("The commands for this program are:\n\n");
  printf("q - to quit the program\n");
  printf("? - to list the accepted commands\n");
  printf("or any postfix mathematical expression using the operators of *, /, +, -\n");

}

// Return size of binary expression tree
int sizeTree(expTree *treeNode) {

  if (treeNode == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    return 1 + sizeTree(treeNode->left) + sizeTree(treeNode->right);
  }

}

// Construct a postfix binary expression tree from expression string
expTree * parseExpression(char *expString) {
  
  char *expStringCopy = (char *)malloc(strlen(expString) + 1);
  expTree *treeNode;
  treeStack expStack;
  initStack(&expStack);

  strcpy(expStringCopy, expString);
  char *expStringTok = strtok(expStringCopy, " ");

  while (expStringTok != NULL) {
    
    if (*expStringTok == '+' || *expStringTok == '-' ||
        *expStringTok == '*' || *expStringTok == '/') {
      if (expStack.used < 2) {
        return NULL;
      }
      treeNode = initTree(expStringTok);
      treeNode->right = popStack(&expStack);
      treeNode->left  = popStack(&expStack);
      pushStack(&expStack, treeNode);
    }
    else {
    
      treeNode = initTree(expStringTok);
      pushStack(&expStack, treeNode);
    
    }
    expStringTok = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  if (expStack.used > 1 || (*(treeNode->val) != '+' && *(treeNode->val) != '-' &&
                            *(treeNode->val) != '*' && *(treeNode->val) != '/')) {
    return NULL;
  }
  free(expStringCopy);
  treeNode = popStack(&expStack);
  clearStack(&expStack);
  return treeNode;
}

// Clear binary expression tree
void clearTree(expTree *rootNode) {
  if (rootNode == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    clearTree(rootNode->left);
    clearTree(rootNode->right);

    free(rootNode->val);
    free(rootNode);
  }
}

// Print infix notation of expression
void printInfix(expTree *rootNode) {
  if (rootNode == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    if (*(rootNode->val) == '+' || *(rootNode->val) == '-' ||
        *(rootNode->val) == '*' || *(rootNode->val) == '/') {
        printf("( ");
    }

    printInfix(rootNode->left);
    printf(" %s ", rootNode->val);
    printInfix(rootNode->right);
  
    if (*(rootNode->val) == '+' || *(rootNode->val) == '-' ||
        *(rootNode->val) == '*' || *(rootNode->val) == '/') {
        printf(" )");
    }
  }
}

// Print prefix notation of expression
void printPrefix(expTree *rootNode) {
  if (rootNode == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    printf(" %s ", rootNode->val);

    printPrefix(rootNode->left);
    printPrefix(rootNode->right);
  }
}

// Evaluate the expression tree
int evalExpression(expTree *rootNode) {
  
  char op;

  if (*(rootNode->val) == '+') {
    return evalExpression(rootNode->left) + evalExpression(rootNode->right);
  }
  else if (*(rootNode->val) == '-') {
    return evalExpression(rootNode->left) - evalExpression(rootNode->right);
  }
  else if (*(rootNode->val) == '*') {
    return evalExpression(rootNode->left) * evalExpression(rootNode->right);
  }
  else if (*(rootNode->val) == '/') {
    return evalExpression(rootNode->left) / evalExpression(rootNode->right);
  }
  else {
    return atoi(rootNode->val);
  }
}




int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{


  char input[300];
  expTree *expPostfix;

  /* set up an infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {


    fgets(input,300,stdin);
    /* remove the newline character from the input */
    int i = 0;

    while (input[i] != '\n' && input[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }   
    input[i] = '\0';

    /* check if user enter q or Q to quit program */
    if ( (strcmp (input, "q") == 0) || (strcmp (input, "Q") == 0) )
      break;
    /* check if user enter ? to see command list */
    else if ( strcmp (input, "?") == 0)
      printCommands();

    /* user enters an expression */
    else {
        // Parse the expression into a binary expression tree
    printf("%s\n", input);
    expPostfix = parseExpression(input);
        
        // Discern whether expression is valid
    if (expPostfix == NULL) {
          printf("Invalid expression. Enter a valid postfix expression \n");
          continue;
    }

    // Print the expression in infix notation
        printf("Infix notation: ");
    printInfix(expPostfix);
        printf("\n");
        
    // Print the expression in prefix notation
        printf("Prefix notation: ");
    printPrefix(expPostfix);
        printf("\n");
        
    // Print the expression in postfix notation
        printf("Postfix notation: ");
    printf("%s\n", input);

    // Evaluate expression and print result
        printf("Expression result: %d \n\n", evalExpression(expPostfix));
    
    clearTree(expPostfix);
    }
   }

  printf("\nGoodbye\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Upon running with Valgrind and an input of "**1 1 -**", this is the output:

```
==35604== 
==35604== HEAP SUMMARY:
==35604==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==35604==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 10 frees, 2,236 bytes allocated
==35604== 
==35604== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==35604==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==35604==    by 0x10952C: initTree (proj4base_38.c:143)
==35604==    by 0x1096CC: parseExpression (proj4base_38.c:194)
==35604==    by 0x109B8A: main (proj4base_38.c:323)
==35604== 
==35604== 48 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==35604==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==35604==    by 0x10952C: initTree (proj4base_38.c:143)
==35604==    by 0x109719: parseExpression (proj4base_38.c:201)
==35604==    by 0x109B8A: main (proj4base_38.c:323)
==35604== 
==35604== LEAK SUMMARY:
==35604==    definitely lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==35604==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==35604==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==35604==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==35604==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==35604== 
==35604== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==35604== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So it seems the culprit is my initTree() function. However, I just cannot wrap my head around why this memory is being lost. I hope this isn't too much code. This is an edit from previously, where someone informed me there was not enough information to go on.

Comment: You can use strdup instead of malloc+strcpy.  Don't cast the result of malloc().  That's the point of void *.  In clearTree() you don't need the else if you return.  initTree &  clearTree do the same number of malloc/free so my guess is that you don't update the result of initTree() somewhere.  Your question good, it's just incomplete so we can't run code to debug it.  What line is proj4base_38.c:194? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A more succinct way to `/* remove the newline character from the input */` is `input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';`.

Comment: Your code doesn't test for EOF from `fgets()`; it should!  I suggest that you should regard `while (1)` loops with suspicion.  They are sometimes necessary, but they're necessary a lot less often than they are used.  Use `while (gets(input, sizeof(input), stdin))` to fix both issues (and to avoid repeating 300 unnecessarily too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leak is caused by **popStack**, because the target of **stackTmp** gets leaked when the function exits:

```
expTree * popStack(treeStack *stack) {
  
  expTree *stackTmp = getTopStack(stack);
  expTree *newNode = (expTree *)malloc(sizeof(expTree));
  *newNode = *stackTmp;

  stack->used -= 1;

  return newNode;
}
```

Given that the stack seemed to be the exclusive owner of the tree, and it no longer has a pointer to it, **popStack** can avoid the leak by simply not making a copy and returning the original:

```
expTree * popStack(treeStack *stack) { 
  expTree *topNode = getTopStack(stack);
  stack->used -= 1;
  return topNode;
}
```

Comment: the reason I made the copy was because I need to clear the stack upon exit from parseExpression(). If I simply return the same pointer from the stack, I can no longer use it once I clear the stack, since the tree node parseExpression returns points to a node in my stack.

Comment: You are popping the top of the stack, so that entry is no longer present to clear.  Please try the change.

Comment: The number of live items in **expTreeDarr** in **expTreeStack** is determined by the **used** field.

Comment: The program seg faults. You're correct about me mistakenly using stack->used instead of stack->height. The stack is never cleared by clearStack(), because by the time it's called, stack->used is 0.

However, upon changing the for loop range in clearStack() from used to height, The returned treeNode from parseExpression() cannot be read. This is what I am attempting to fix now. Your suggestion did indeed point me in the right direction

Comment: My point was that **used**  determines the number of live items, but I did not mean this to be interpreted as a suggestion to change **clearStack** in any way.   My point was that when **popStack** removes an entry from the stack, the values in that removed entry are meaningless.  The **height** field is misnamed as it actually represents the capacity of the dynamically allocated buffer to store stack entries.  What I suggest is that you go back to your original program posted in the question (without any changes to **clearStack**) and just change **popStack** as I have described.  That works.